# Short story - US and USSR "trade" cities after accidental bombing

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, nuclear-weapons

This is a short story I read in the 1980s in an anthology. It's a satirical story inspired by ["Fail Safe"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fail_Safe_(1964_film)), I think.  In the story, US bombers accidentally destroy a Soviet city (Leningrad, I think), and the US offers the Soviets the opportunity to destroy an equivalent US city in exchange - but what counts as equivalent?  More and more cities are destroyed in a slow-motion apocalypse as the nations try to even the score (if I recall correctly, Boston is destroyed as a equivalent of Leningrad, at first, but after Boston is destroyed, the Soviets recall that Leningrad also was a center of movie production, so Hollywood is now on the table for destruction, etc.).

Comment: U are saying, both sides disagree that two cities are exactly equivalent and so, sort of like pulling covers from your spouse on a cold night, it just continues? The idea makes me more nauseous than amused, but I am intrigued about the author and title now because I never heard of it.

Comment: For novel length treatment of a negotiated "tit for tat", see _Fail Safe_ by Eugene Burdick and Harvey Wheeler. There was a film made based on it. For black humor treatment of the idea, of course, see Doctor Strangelove.

Comment: That would be Stanley Kubrick's "Dr. Strangelove or: How I Learned to Stop Worrying and Love the Bomb" :)

Comment: @keshlam: He indicates it is not Fail Safe and Fail Safe lacks the satirical "log-rolling" aspect which is a powerful variation: Wait, did we not used to make movies in Leningrad? Okay, we need to bomb Hollywood -- THEN everyone is even. (Until the Americans decide they now need to get Odessa because Santa Monica and Malibu are radioactive...)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

And of course, searching ISFDB for "Boston" finds it: Herbert Gold's [The Day They Got Boston](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?74473)

This [review](http://galacticjourney.org/august-26-1961-introduce-yourself-september-1961-fantasy-and-science-fiction/) confirms:

> Moving on, we have Herbert Gold’s satirical The Day They Got Boston,
> about the diplomatic tit-for-tat that might ensue should the Soviets
> ever accidentally blow up one of our cities.

Apparently, I misremembered who was responsible for the first accident.

I probably read it in [Political Science Fiction: An Introductory Reader](https://isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?614400)